# Install app from android browser

Tags: android, android-intent

I created an app that installs another app from an apk file on the sd card:

```
File fullPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test_intent_target.apk");

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(fullPath);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

startActivity(intent);
```

I then used log to get the intent as a string:

```
Log.d("my intent", intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME));
```

which produces:

```
intent:///mnt/sdcard/test_intent_target.apk#Intent;scheme=file;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;type=application/vnd.android.package-archive;end
```

I now want to create a link in a web browser that launches that intent. I've tried:

```
<a href="intent:///mnt/sdcard/test_intent_target.apk#Intent;scheme=file;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;type=application/vnd.android.package-archive;end">Install App</a>
```

but the web browser just comes back with page not available. I keep seeing examples of people using `<a href="intent:#Intent;etc;etc;end>` but it doesn't seem to work for me, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help or clues here would be appreciated

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 1):

`<a href="file:///mnt/sdcard/....">` Also, not sure if you need the part after .apk.

Comment: Tried it on the default browser for cyanogenmod 7, on opera mini and on the amazon kindle browser on two separate devices and it doesn't work. Just doesn't do anything. No app installed no package installer launched. Just seems to refresh the webpage.

Comment: Actually, it works if I long press and open in a new window in Amazon browser and the cyanogen mod default browser, but not on opera. Adding in `target="blank"` doesn't make a difference